# C recursive function not possible?

Tags: c, algorithm, tree

I am trying to write a recursive function that gets a root of tree and returns the sum of all child nodes (excluding the root node), So I wrote:

```
int my_func_in(node *root)
{
    int result = root->value;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_childs; ++i)
    {
        result += my_func_in(root->child[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

int my_func(node *root)
{
    if (!root) return 0;
    return my_func_in(root);
}
```

This code will calculate the sum of the root too, I can solve this by using a minus operator at the end of `my_func`, but is there a cleaner solution or algorithm?

Comment: @GoodDeeds if ```result = 0``` then what the ```my_func_in``` will return? As we are not summing anything.

Comment: @BadhanSen Sorry, commented in a hurry, you're right.

Comment: @BadhanSen how we are not summing anything? please see result +=...

Comment: I replied @GoodDeeds comment. I think he deletes his comment.

Comment: If you want "the sum of all child nodes" then why you implementing your recursive function to sum the root node? Just replace assignment `result=root->value` with `result = 0` and add line `result += root->child[i]->value;` into the `foo` loop.

Comment: Just use `static int counter` in each child, or `_Thread_local static int counter` for thread safe static.

Answer (score 2):

As we are not considering the root, so we will only add the child nodes value with the answer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

#define numberOfChild 26

struct Node{
    int value;
    struct Node *child[numberOfChild];
};

struct Node* getNewNode(int val)
{
    struct Node* root = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    root->value = val;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfChild; i++) {
        root->child[i] = NULL;
    }
    return root;
}

int totalSum;

void inorder(struct Node* root){
    if(root == NULL) return;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < numberOfChild; i++){
        if(root->child[i] != NULL){
            totalSum += root->child[i]->value;
            inorder(root->child[i]);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    totalSum = 0;
    struct Node* root = getNewNode(1);
    root->child[2] = getNewNode(2);
    root->child[4] = getNewNode(3);
    root->child[2]->child[1] = getNewNode(4);
    root->child[4]->child[2] = getNewNode(5);

    inorder(root);
    printf("%d\n", totalSum);
    return 0;
}
// summation 14
```

Comment: this is C++, not C

Comment: @tstanisl, Thanks for pointing it out. I updated the code in ```C``` language.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just considering the child arrays :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct node s_node;
struct node{
    int value;
    s_node **child;
};
int my_func_in(s_node **childs)
{
    if (!childs) return 0;
    int lSum = 0;
    while(*childs != NULL) { 
       lSum+=childs[0]->value+my_func_in(childs[0]->child);childs++;
    }
    return lSum;
}

int my_func(s_node *root)
{
    if (!root) return 0;
    return my_func_in(root->child);
}
int main(int nbargs, char *args[]) {
   s_node c1c1 = { 2, (s_node **) NULL };
   s_node c1c2c1 = { 6, (s_node **)NULL };
   s_node c1c2 = { 1,  (s_node*[]){ &c1c2c1, (s_node *)NULL } };
   s_node c3c1 = { 8, (s_node **)NULL };
   s_node c3c2c1c1 = { 9, (s_node **)NULL };
   s_node c3c2c1 = { 1, (s_node*[]){ &c3c2c1c1, (s_node *)NULL } };
   s_node c3c2 = { 4, (s_node*[]){ &c3c2c1, (s_node *)NULL } };
   s_node rc1 = { 7, (s_node*[]){ &c1c1, &c1c2, (s_node *)NULL }  };
   s_node rc2 = { 4, (s_node **)NULL };
   s_node rc3 = { 3, (s_node*[]){ &c3c1, &c3c2, (s_node *)NULL }  };
   s_node root = { 44, (s_node*[]){ &rc1, &rc2, &rc3, (s_node *)NULL}};
   int lRes = my_func(&root);
   printf("Sum: %d\n", lRes);
}
```

Output:

```
Sum: 45
```

**EDIT:**

As suggested by @tstanisl in the comments, the `NULL` casts in the `main` can be discarded as they are here to make visible that there is *"NULL array terminators"* and *"There is no array"*.

Like @tstanisl remarks it, there is also no more need of `my_func` as it only serves to check that there is a root pointer. So you should **remove it** and rename `my_func_in` in `my_func`. You can then directly call it from `main` with : `int lRes = my_func(root.child);`. With node **pointers**, you should still check them before dereferencing them, that can be done with a simple ternary check : `int process(s_node *pRoot) { int lMyRes = pRoot!=NULL?my_func(pRoot->child):0; /* Doing other stuff */ }`.

Here is the corresponding code from our example :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct node s_node;
struct node{
    int value;
    s_node **child;
};
int my_func(s_node **childs)
{
    if (!childs) return 0;
    int lSum = 0;
    while(*childs != NULL) { 
       lSum+=childs[0]->value+my_func(childs[0]->child);childs++;
    }
    return lSum;
}

int main(int nbargs, char *args[]) {
   s_node c1c1 = { 2, NULL };
   s_node c1c2c1 = { 6, NULL };
   s_node c1c2 = { 1,  (s_node*[]){ &c1c2c1, NULL } };
   s_node c3c1 = { 8, NULL };
   s_node c3c2c1c1 = { 9, NULL };
   s_node c3c2c1 = { 1, (s_node*[]){ &c3c2c1c1, NULL } };
   s_node c3c2 = { 4, (s_node*[]){ &c3c2c1, NULL } };
   s_node rc1 = { 7, (s_node*[]){ &c1c1, &c1c2, NULL }  };
   s_node rc2 = { 4, NULL };
   s_node rc3 = { 3, (s_node*[]){ &c3c1, &c3c2, NULL }  };
   s_node root = { 44, (s_node*[]){ &rc1, &rc2, &rc3, NULL}};
   int lRes = my_func(root.child);
   printf("Sum: %d\n", lRes);
}
```

Comment: don't cast `NULL`, it is redundant and only makes code less readable

Comment: moreover, there is no need for `my_func`, just rename `my_func_in` to `my_func`

Comment: @tstanisl You're right.  However, it seems to me useful here to keep NULL casting to show that there is a _"NULL array terminator"_  which should not be confused with _"there is no array"_.  For  `my_func` and `my_func_in`, i've adapted from OP code in its question, so its a way to keep this link visible. I will add anyway your useful remarks in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 mutually recursive functions. Also `num_of_childs` appears to be a global variable or constant: it would be cleaner to make it a member of the `node` structure.

Here is an example:

```
struct node {
    int value;
    int count;
    struct node *child[];  // this is a flexible array
};

int sum_children(const node *root);

int sum_subtree(const node *root) {
    if (root)
        return root->value + sum_children(root);
    else
        return 0;
}

int sum_children(const node *root) {
    int result = 0;
    if (root) {
        for (int i = 0; i < root->count; ++i)
            result += sum_subtree(root->child[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```